# An error occurs when uploading additional galleries in MAUI(C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

When uploading images in the gallery, the first time is normal, but an error occurs when additional images are uploaded.

Could you please confirm what could be the problem?

**Error string :**

*System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'*

The source below is my source uploaded on Github.

[My source in Github](https://github.com/pi314267/MAUI_ErrorTest_PickingImage_StreamError)

This is My Viewmodel variable.

```
private IEnumerable<PickImages> selectedItems;
    public IEnumerable<PickImages> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedItems, value);
        }
    }
```

And This is My Model Class

```
public class PickImages
{  
    public ImageSource CombineDeleteMarkImage { get; set; }

    public string MainImageYN { get; set; }
}
```

And I set My variable(selectedItems) Like this in viewModel

```
void Pick(View view, params MediaFileType[] types)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts = null;
                
                try
                {
                    //DisposeItems();

                    cts = new CancellationTokenSource(
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000000));

                    var result = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(
                        new MediaPickRequest(SelectionLimit, types)
                        {
                            Title = $"Select {SelectionLimit} photos",
                            PresentationSourceBounds = view?.GetAbsoluteBounds(40),
                            UseCreateChooser = UseCreateChooser
                        },
                        cts.Token);

                    List<Image> liImageSource= new List<Image>();


                    List<PickImages> list = new List<PickImages>();
                    if (SelectedItems != null)
                        list = SelectedItems.ToList();

                    foreach (var item in await SetImage(result))
                    {

                        if (list.Count > 10)
                        {
                            return;
                        }


                        Image image = ImageHelper.ImageThumnailMaker(item);


                        bool blcheckMainimg = false;
                        foreach (var s_item in list)
                        {
                            if (s_item.MainImageYN.Equals("Y"))
                            {
                                blcheckMainimg = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                      
                        if (blcheckMainimg)
                        {
                            list.Add(new PickImages { CombineDeleteMarkImage = image.Source, MainImageYN = "N" });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            
                            //Image mImage = ImageHelper.CombineWithMain(item);
                            list.Add(new PickImages { CombineDeleteMarkImage = image.Source, MainImageYN = "Y" });
                        }

                    }


                    SelectedItems = list;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OperationInfo = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cts?.Dispose();
                    
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

When registering an image for the first time, it is normal, but when registering an additional image from the original gallery image, a Stream Error occurs.

And this is my xaml.

```
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentView Padding="0,8">
                                        <Grid>  
                                            <AbsoluteLayout>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding SelectedItems.CombineDeleteMarkImage}"
                                                        WidthRequest="80"
                                                        HeightRequest="80"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                                                <myc:MyBoxView  
                                                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,0.3,0.3"
                                                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                                    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                            Command="{Binding BoxViewTapCommand}"
                                                            />
                                                    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </myc:MyBoxView>
                                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                Command="{Binding ImageTapGestureCommand}"/>
                                        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </ContentView>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Relevant code needs to be posted and formatted properly in the body of your post, not as a link to an external repo

Comment: @Jason I edited My ask. This is my first time registering, so there is a clumsy part. Thank you for your understanding

Comment: which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: @Jason A Stream error occurs when a List is added to selectedItems and then a List is additionally added to SelectedItems.
 It is not possible to confirm the exact reason.

Comment: Of course it is.  Either step through the code in the debugger until the exception occurs, or look at the stack trace attached to the exception object that should show you the line number.  This is basic C# debugging

Comment: @Jason I've already done that, but I have a feeling that something is outputting an error internally. Debugging doesn't catch it, so I can't figure out the exact cause, so I'm also frustrated.